# curve fitting error for optimal parameters while using scipy optimize curvefit in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I am getting optimization errors while creating map of h3 moments using a self-defined function get_h3 in python for an image file called "image_test". The idea is to obtain h3 moments by curve fitting for the velocity values in each cell of my x-y grid and plotting those corresponding values in each cell as a heatmap. The link to my code (image_stats_NEW.ipynb) in my drive is below. The code uses a file "image_test" which needs to be downloaded for code to run.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1gXWSuxsOHHaNV5Qv-C1f4kEUwElKMmRS?usp=sharing

I think the initial guesses p0 need to be better. How will I know what values to use or is there a better way to automatically generate good initial guesses? If you think something else is the issue please feel free to comment. I am posting here snippet of the code but full code with data is available in the google drive link. Thanks a lot for the help!

```
def get_h3(dataV):
    if len(dataV)==0:
        #np.all(a==0)
        return 0
    else:
        counts, binz = np.histogram(dataV, density=True, bins=150)
        x_h = binz[:-1]
        y_h = counts
        n = len(x_h)                            
        mean = sum(x_h*y_h)/n   #mean and sig of probability distribution calculated like this                
        sigma = sum(y_h*(x_h-mean)**2)/n        

    # Let's define the Gauss-Hermite function #a=amplitude, x0=location of peak, sig=std dev, h3, h4
        def gh_func(x_h, a, x0, sig, h3, h4):
            return a*np.exp(-.5*((x_h-x0)/sig)**2)*(1+h3*((-np.sqrt(3))*((x_h-x0)/sig)+(2/np.sqrt(3))*((x_h-x0)/sig)**3)+ h4*((np.sqrt(6)/4)+(-np.sqrt(6))*((x_h-x0)/sig)**2+(np.sqrt(6)/3)*(((x_h-x0)/sig)**4)))
        popt, pcov = curve_fit(gh_func, x_h, y_h, p0=( np.max(y_h), mean, sigma, 0, 0 ), maxfev=10000) #i'm taking h3=0 and h4=0 as guesses
        return popt[3] #this popt[3] is our h3 value
####-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#getting h3 from velocity values in each cell
h3 = [[[] for y_new in range(k)] for x_new in range(k)]
for ycell in range(k):
    for xcell in range(k):
        cells[ycell][xcell] = vz_new[(y_new == ycell) & (x_new == xcell)]
        h3[ycell][xcell] = get_h3(cells[ycell][xcell])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax=sns.heatmap(h3, cmap='RdBu')
ax.invert_yaxis()
plt.show()
```

ERROR I get when I call the function:RuntimeError: Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 10000.

Comment: Can you just provide one single data set that fails. That would make testing easier. Some comments. `len(dataV)==0` seems ok, but actually fitting only makes sense if you have five or more points. First making a histogramm and then fitting the pdf is probably not as good as making a maximum likelihood

Comment: @mikuszefski, I think it's failing when the cells are empty....some cells are empty..how to make a maximum likelihood? feel free to play around with my code and data if you like:https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1gXWSuxsOHHaNV5Qv-C1f4kEUwElKMmRS?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you provide one data set as csv, please.

Comment: Also, I have a fundamental problem. The fit function can become negative. That cannot be a distribution function, can it.

Comment: @mikuszefski, tysm and I have added csv files of the x,y,vz arrays in my google drive:https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1gXWSuxsOHHaNV5Qv-C1f4kEUwElKMmRS?usp=sharing. Also, sorry, what do you mean that the fit function becomes negative? It is a gauss-hermite function that has high order moments like skewness and kurtosis, that's why i guess it can become negative..

Comment: how do `x`, `y` and `vz` appear in `dataV`, meaning, what data do you use for the histogram. What I mean by negative: You are fitting counts, which are by definition >=0. A negative fit-function, hence, does not make sense.  I know Hermite polynomials from the [quantum harmonic oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator#/media/File:HarmOsziFunktionen.png). A [skewed Gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution) is a different animal.

Comment: @mikuszefski the data for the histogram is the frequency distribution of the vz values. For the histogram, on vertical axis we have counts and on horizontal axis we have bins. I am trying to find the h3 moment from this histogram.

Comment: After looking at the data, I do not see how this should be fitted by Hermite polynomials. What is the origin of choice for this fitting-function?

Comment: @mikuszefski, sorry but what do you mean by origin of choice? It's just velocity distributions from stars in a galaxy. The simplest curve fit would be a Gaussian but we can find what the mean velocity is or what the variance is from the velocity values for every pixel in the x-y grid. Similarly, we can find h3 moments from the velocity values by curve fitting. The function I defined `get_h3()` seems to work upto cells[10][10] but not beyond,i.e. they are fitted by hermite polynomials upto that.

Comment: @mikuszefski, also, why do you say they cannot be fiitted by hermite polynomials?

Comment: Well, to my understanding a distribution function (from a physics point of view) would describe the number of counts per bin. I cannot have negative counts, i.e. I'd require form the function to be `f(x) >=0` for all `x`. This is not true for the function that you are fitting. So my question is, why do you think that Hermite polynomials describe your measured velocity distribution? In the data I see a type of double peak that looks like  the superposition of two skewed ones with excess Kurtosis.

Comment: @mikuszefski, it's just that I think even if the velocity distribution may not fit well to a gauss-hermite it should be possible to make some fit and get h3 (skewness) or h4 (kurtosis) values...there are many such galaxy simulations that are used to make h3, h4 maps so I think this should work as well.

Comment: Well, if you are just interested in the moments of the distribution, just calculate them from the data: mu = E[x], s^2 = E[ (x-mu)^2 ], mu3 = E[ (  x-mu )^3 ] and mu4= E[ ( x-mu )^4 ]. No fit required.